# Php word find game in Baltic characters problems "ū" is equal to "ī" but why

Tags: php, string, special-characters, double-byte, scrabble

found some cool code to generate words from given letters in English language it works flawlessly,
but to use some special characters it has some glitches it thinks that "**ū**" is equal to "**ī**" you can try adding "**drūtsjē**" and it somehow finds "**tīrs**","**rīts**", "**x**"...
why is it and how it is possible to fix it ?
dont forget to check **Unikāli burti:**
here is some code
**index.php**

```
<?php
    //Require the word finder class
    require_once("com/app/word_finder/word_finder.php");
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="message_box">
            <hr />
            <form method="get">
                <ul id="submitform">
                    <li><label for="word"><strong>Burti:</strong></label><input type="text" name="word" id="word" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['word']) ? $_GET['word'] : ""; ?>" /></li>
                    <li><label for="match_letter_count"><strong>Unikāli burti:</strong></label><input type="checkbox" name="match_letter_count" id="match_letter_count" value="1" <?php echo isset($_GET['match_letter_count']) && $_GET['match_letter_count'] == "1"  ? "checked='checked'" : "0"; ?>/></li>
                    <li><label for="strict"><strong>Noteikti burti:</strong></label><input type="checkbox" name="strict" id="strict" value="1" <?php echo isset($_GET['strict']) && $_GET['strict'] == "1"  ? "checked='checked'" : "0"; ?> /></li>
                    <!-- <li><label for="lrt_count"><strong>min 3 burti:</strong></label><input type="checkbox" name="lrt_count" id="lrt_count" value="1" < ?php echo isset($_GET['lrt_count']) && $_GET['lrt_count'] == "1"  ? "checked='checked'" : "0"; ?> /></li> -->
                    <li><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Spēlēt" /></li>
                </ul>
            </form>
            
            <?php
            
            
            
                //Example Usage
                if(isset($_GET['word']) && $_GET['word'] != NULL) {
                    
                    //The required usage to get the return array
                    $Word_Finders = new Com\App\Word_Finder($_GET['word'], isset($_GET['strict']) ? TRUE : FALSE, isset($_GET['match_letter_count']) ? TRUE : FALSE);
                    $arrWord_Finders = $Word_Finders->getWords();
                    //The required usage to get the return array
                    
                    //Echo out the results
                    echo '<h1>Atrasti</h1>';
                    echo "<ul id='wordlist'>";
                        foreach($arrWord_Finders as $anagram) {
                            echo "<li>" . $anagram . " (" . (grapheme_strlen($anagram)-1). ")</li>";
                        }
                    echo "</ul>";
                }
            ?>
            
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

and
**word_finder.php**

```
<?php

namespace Com\App {

    /*
    * This class can be used to search for words within other words, or find 
    * out what words can be made using reusable letters for example. It can
    * also be used to solve countdown conundrums and other related issues.
    *
    * It uses an experimental method by reading in the entire dictionary, then
    * eliminating words one by one until it's left with the desired array.
    *
    * @version 1.0
    * @copyright 2012 Mark Gannaway <mark@ganners.co.uk>
    * @link http://ganners.co.uk
    * @license LGPL
    */
    class Word_Finder {
        
        private $word,
            $dictionary = array(),
            $alphabet = array();
        
        /**
        * Public construct - used to define all required variables
        * @param (string) $word - The inputted word/letters to be searched
        * @param (bool) $strict - If the search is strict - which means it must use all letters at least once
        * @param (bool) $match_letter_count - This will mean it should match the maximum letter count, so the words can't reuse letters
        * @return void
        */
        public function __construct($word, $strict = FALSE, $match_letter_count = FALSE, $lrt_count = FALSE) {
            
            //Sets the word to the lowercase array of letters
            $this->word = (array) str_split(strtolower($word));
            
            //Reads in the dictionary
            $this->dictionary = $this->getDictionary(dirname(__FILE__) . "/words.latvian");
            
            //Grabs the alphabet array
            $this->alphabet = $this->getFilteredAlphabetArray();
            
            //Performs the initial array magic and will loosely filter out words which don't contain any of the letters
            $this->filterLoose();
            
            //Will match the maximum letter counts if true
            if($match_letter_count) {
                $this->matchLetterCounts();
            }
            
            //Will strict search if true
            if($strict) {
                $this->filterStrict();
            }
            
            
            // vaardi saakot ar burtu daudzumu
            if($lrt_count){
                
            }
            
        }
        
        /**
        * Will retrieve the words and perform a sort by string length
        * @param void
        * @return void
        */
        public function getWords() {
        
            $sortArray = function($a, $b) {
                return grapheme_strlen($b)-grapheme_strlen($a);
            };
        
            usort($this->dictionary, $sortArray);
            return $this->dictionary;
        
        }
        
        /**
        * Will read in the dictionary file and return the array
        * @param (string) $file_name - The location of the dictionary file
        * @return (array) The dictionary array
        */
        private function getDictionary($file_name) {
            $dictionary_file = file_get_contents($file_name);
            return (array) explode("\n", $dictionary_file);
        }
        
        /**
        * This will create an alphabet based on the letters that aren't in the inputted word.
        * @param void
        * @return (array) $alphabet - The alphabet containing words not in the object's word
        */
        private function getFilteredAlphabetArray() {
        
            $alphabet = str_split("aābcčdeēfgģhiījkķlļmnņoprsštuūvzž");
            
            foreach($this->word as $wordLetter) {
                foreach($alphabet as $key => $alphabetLetter) {
                    if($wordLetter == $alphabetLetter) {
                        unset($alphabet[$key]);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            return (array) $alphabet;
        }
        
        /**
        * This will filter out words which don't contain any letters from the formatted alphabet
        * @param void
        * @return void
        */
        private function filterLoose() {
            foreach($this->alphabet as $letter) {
                foreach($this->dictionary as $key => $word) {
                    $wordArr = str_split(strtolower($word));
                    if(in_array($letter, $wordArr)) {
                        unset($this->dictionary[$key]);
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        /**
        * This will filter out words which don't contain all letters from the formatted alphabet
        * @param void
        * @return void
        */
        private function filterStrict() {
            foreach($this->word as $wordLetter) {
                foreach($this->dictionary as $key => $word) {
                    $wordArr = str_split($word);
                    if(!in_array($wordLetter, $wordArr)) {
                        unset($this->dictionary[$key]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        /**
        * This will filter out words which don't contain more individual letters than that in the original word
        * @param void
        * @return void
        */
        private function matchLetterCounts() {
        
            foreach($this->dictionary as $key => $dictionary_word) {
                $dictionary_word_count_values = array_count_values(str_split(strtolower($dictionary_word)));
                $word_count_values = array_count_values($this->word);
                
                foreach($word_count_values as $letter_count_value => $letter_count_amount) {
                    if(isset($dictionary_word_count_values[$letter_count_value]) && ($letter_count_amount < $dictionary_word_count_values[$letter_count_value])) {
                        unset($this->dictionary[$key]);
                    }
                }
                
            }
        
        }
        
    }
}
?>
```

**words.latvian**

```
dūrējs
rūsēt
trūds
tīrs
rīts
rūts
trīs
tūrs
ērts
ūdrs
jērs
dēts
sūt
īrs
ēst
tīs
sēt
jūs
dēt
dēs
rīs
jūt
Jūs
rīt
ST
ēd
ts
sū
x
```

thanks for helping

Comment: I think this has to do with [multi-byte-characters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php). You could try to replace typical single-byte-character functions by multi-byte-character functions.

Comment: "mb_str_split" did the trick. Thanks